# Why my discord bot ctx .send command not working and it do not show any error?

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

``

```
global p1
global p2
global p1_ans
global p2_ans
global gameOver
@client.command()
async def playrps(ctx,p1: discord.Member, p2:discord.Member):
            gameOver = False
            turn = p1
            await ctx.send('Type Rock/Paper/Scissor on your turn','It is',{p1.mention},'turn')  
            #switch turns
            while not gameOver:
             if turn == p1:
              turn = p2
              clear()
             else:
              turn = p1
              clear()
```

```
type here
```

The playrps command not working , someone pls help thanks --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: You'll have to provide a lot more information than this. Which intents did you enable? How are you running your bot? Do you have logging enabled? Do you have an error handler?

Comment: could you plz share your `import` and `bot` declarations/initializations ? Also, your use of `global` is wrong, you declare your variable outside of functions, but you tell the python interpreter which are global inside functions. Last but not least, your `send()` argument is not good, `send()` needing only one argument, a string. Two ways for that, or `send("R/P/S game - player to start :"+p1.name)`, or `send(f"R/P/S game - player to start : {p1.name}")`

Comment: There are a bunch  of things that are wrong and missing in that code block.